# Swift parse server error

Tags: swift

I am trying to save a test object to my parse server, when I do that I get this error:

> Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.})

My parse configuration looks like this:

```
let configuration = ParseClientConfiguration {
    $0.applicationId = "myAppID"
    $0.clientKey = "myClientKey"
    $0.server = "http://myPublicDNS"
}
Parse.initialize(with: configuration)
```

my data save function looks like this:

```
let test = PFObject(className:"test")
test["int"] = 1337
test["str"] = "Sean Plott"
test.saveInBackground {
    (success: Bool, error: Error?) in
        if (success) {
            // The object has been saved.
            print("succes")
        } else {
            // There was a problem, check error.description
            print(error)
        }
}
```

This is the class screen of the attributes this class needs.

[parse test class screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AF6l.png)

How can I fix the annoying error?
Thanks in advance,
Sander

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for the replies, but I found out that I used the wrong server url.

Answer (score 1):

This error comes when we have not sending correct data to backend server or this comes from back end  side .
you have check with back end server is you are sending correct data what they need .You may also check this on Postman also.

Comment: I think I sent the correct data, see the screenshot in the question.
Also I don't really know that you mean with Postman.
Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: On post man you can check response of back end service  you have to provide url and data it will return respose,if you are sending correct data then it's back end error. check it on postman or any other online API checker App.